# Enum injection or code change?

Tags: c#, parsing, .net-4.0, enums, .net-4.5

We have a gender *enum* something like

```
enum Gender
{
  female=0,
  male=1,
}
```

and the users are allowed to enter either `'male'` or  `'female'`. All is well.
But tomorrow if the users just enter `'m'` or `'f'` it has to be `'male'` or `'female'`.
(In general, short forms `'m'` or `'f'` should be supported)

Is there anyway, If I modify the *enum* or (any *enum* injection stuff at runtime) this can be achieved?

For now, I just use

```
 string value = GetUserInput();
 if (userEnteredValue == 'm')
 {
     value = "male";
 }
 else if (userEnteredValue == 'f')
 {
     value = "female";
 }
 //else enum.tryparse(stuff)
```

but wondering if there are any nicer way to do this? Instead of all the if-else structures.

Comment: you can use StartWith right? or something like autocomplete/search capabilities in the input

Comment: @arifnpm: Why should I use StartWith ? Find no reasons to do it

Comment: maybe you can implement custom parse logic in extension method? http://kirillosenkov.blogspot.com/2007/09/making-c-enums-more-usable-parse-method.html

Comment: so you want to apply annotation only 'm' for 'male' and 'f' for female in the enum?

Comment: @Arie: a good catch... Thanks for that.. "A custom parse logic?" Seems good idea to me..thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I strongly recommend to convert the user input to 0/1 using a fixed set of options and not free text.

but if you must one possibility is to use a custom attribute.
so it would look something like that:

```
enum Gender
{

  [Synonyms("f","female","FL")]
  female=0,
  [Synonyms("m","male","ML")]
  male=1,
}
```

the attribute should look something like that:

```
public sealed class Synonyms: Attribute
{
    private readonly string[] values;

    public AbbreviationAttribute(params string[] i_Values)
    {
        this.values = i_Values;
    }

    public string Values
    {
        get { return this.values; }
    }
}
```

then use a generic method to retrieve your possible synonyms

```
public static R GetAttributeValue<T, R>(IConvertible @enum)
{
    R attributeValue = default(R);

    if (@enum != null)
    {
        FieldInfo fi = @enum.GetType().GetField(@enum.ToString());

        if (fi != null)
        {
            T[] attributes = fi.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(T), false) as T[];

            if (attributes != null && attributes.Length > 0)
            {
                IAttribute<R> attribute = attributes[0] as IAttribute<R>;

                if (attribute != null)
                {
                    attributeValue = attribute.Value;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return attributeValue;


}
```

then use the method above to retrieve the array of values in the array and compare the user input.

*EDIT:*
if fore some reason you have no access to the enum values, there is no other choice than to use an if ... else... statements just be sure to encapsulate that login in a separate function or class according to reusability requirements.

```
public eGender getEnumFrom UserInput(string i_userInput)
{
   if(i_userInput == "male") then return eGender.male;
   if(i_userInput == "m") then return eGender.male;
   if(i_userInput == "ML") then return eGender.male;
....
}
```

Comment: Thanks.. But just out of curiosity. What happens when I can't modify an enum ? May be in the cases of enum serialization or when I am referring to a third party supplied enumerations ?

Comment: If that is the case the you have no other choice than to use IF ELSE, just be sure to encapsulate that in a single method.. I'll post an example

Answer (score 1):

If your program has some sort of UI, I would suggest do not touch underline data structure, till you *really* need that. Especially if you already developed a production code with this.

I would suggest just on you UI layer accept "m" and "f" as well, like an enhancement of your app functionality, but after t convert to "mail", "female".

In this way you will get a flexibility: if one day you would like to make another changes (enhance more) just change "conversion layer" and all works like before. Think also about multilanguage environment.

Comment: Unfortunately, this input is got from a PDF file, so I cannot do it in the UI layer

Comment: @nowhewhomustnotbenamed.: but you can create "conversion layer", that accepts data in any supported format, and transforms it in solid datalayer format. And vice versa.

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of display annotation

```
enum Gender
{
  [Display(Name="f")]
  female=0,
  [Display(Name="m")]
  male=1,
}
```